# How to display user submitted values from django forms in the same HTML page

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, web-frameworks

I wanted to display user-submitted values in the same HTML page. I'm able to display those values but it comes in python dictionary format. I'm getting the result: `'first_name': 'Tom', 'last_name': 'Hanks'}`, Is there any way to display only First Name and Last Name separately.

This is views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms


class DbNames(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label="First Name")
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="Last Name")


def index(request):
    return render(request, "emp/index.html")


def form_gen(request):
    form = DbNames()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DbNames(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, "emp/users.html", {
                "form_data": form.cleaned_data
            })
        else:
            print('ERROR')
    return render(request, "emp/users.html", {
        "result": form
    })
```

Comment: Have you checked Django templates? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/

Comment: @Anvesh thanks. I changed the template {{form_data.first_name}} and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def form_gen(request):
    form = DbNames()
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        form = DbNames(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Because form.cleaned_data return a dict
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            return render(request, "emp/users.html", {
                "first_name": first_name, "last_name": last_name,
            })
        else:
            print('ERROR')
    return render(request, "emp/users.html", {
        "result": form
    })
```

And to access these values in your template which `"emp/users.html"` in your case. You can use django-template-language syntax like this:

```html
<p>{{ first_name }} </p>
<p>{{ last_name }}</p>
```